# String -> Time/Date casting in Varnish 3.0.4

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

does anybody know how to cast header string (ie. Last-Modified Fri, 11 Dec 2015 07:31:48 GMT) to Time Type in Varnish 3.0.4. I know that in the newest version of Varsnih, there are time-specific methods in std vmod, but i don't know how can do similar thing in my version.

Answer (score 0):

You can inline C this in your vcl. With Varnish 3 inline C is on by default. From here you can make it into a vmod but this should work as is (add this to vcl sub):

```
C{
   char time_str[128];

   // Format time however you need it
   sprintf(time_str, "%ld", time());

   VRT_SetHdr(sp, HDR_REQ, "\016Last-Modified:", time_str, vrt_magic_string_end);
}C
```